# user Input Date in the form 01-Jun-2013 and output be 6 i.e., current day of week, using java i.e., swings

Tags: java, swing, date, datetime

for example:
Monday-1,
tuesday-2,
wednesday-3,
thursday-4,
friday-5,
saturday-6,
sunday-7,

if my input is 01-Jun-2013 then my output should be 6,
if my input is 02-Jun-2013 then my output should be 7,
if my input is 03-Jun-2013 then my output should be 1,

I need code in java(swings).This is my requirement, I tried in many ways but i'm getting only 7 Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: This looks too much like a homework question. We won't do the code for you.

Comment: google for "how to parse date in Java". I'm sure you get a gazillion answers.

Comment: I'm new to java plz help to me. I'm preparing small attendence app in this i need this small pice of code.I'm not able to do this.

Comment: This is not the place for homework. And this is not whatsapp. Please write correctly. "plz" ???

Comment: Instead of begging, do what you've been asked to do: post the code you tried.

Answer (score 2):

I will point you in a direction, but you have to do the work since everyone else seems to think you are a student trying to get us to do your homework.  Visit this site and check out the Calendar class.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Date is also another good Class to know.

Comment: Ok, this is my last help on this matter.  new Calendar() is initialized with today's Date.  The static call to Calendar is also set to today's date.  So, Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK is 7 since today is Sunday.  If you called Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK tomorrow it will return 1.  After you initialize a Calendar object, you have to set the date to the date you want and then get(DAY_OF_WEEK).  Read through the methods listed in the api.  Take time to understand them.  It will help you with future quests.